# Mod Rewrite lost all GET parameters [PHP]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Today i start with my mod rewrite for the php script.
Some words to the setup

I use a subdomain e.g. test.testsystem.com which points to root/test/
So i have some multiple GET Parameters for my PHP script like the following:

```
1) https://test.testsystem.com/index.php?a=foo
2) https://test.testsystem.com/index.php?a=foo&v=bar
3) https://test.testsystem.com/index.php?a=foo&c=testcode
```

so with mod rewrite i want to have

```
1) https://test.testsystem.com/foo
2) https://test.testsystem.com/foo/bar
3) https://test.testsystem.com/foo/c/testcode
```

What i currently have is

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?a=$1&v=$2 [QSA]
```

For the first two URLs. Now it does no error 500 any more but the problem is i do not get any GET parameters in my php script.

Maybe someone can provide me here a working solution.

Regards

Comment: Your rules both demand that the requested URL path begins with two letters followed by a slash. None of the three input URL examples you have mentioned satisfy that condition to begin with.

Comment: And trying to match the _exact same_ pattern in two consecutive rules does make very little sense as well.

Comment: yes you are right i changed it to
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA]

for the first rule but it also did not work

Comment: Does it work for your first URI `RewriteRule ^foo$ index.php?a=foo [L]` Type the /foo in your address bar just to see if you get `foo` variable in your php script.

Comment: i tested it with https://test.testsystem.com/foo
and in the index.php i use following: 
`$request = array_merge($_GET, $_POST); 
print_r($request);`

all what i got was array().... so no entry within the array

Comment: ok now i uploaded a new .htaccess file and with foo in the adress bar i got an 404

Comment: `Options -Multiviews
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /test/
 RewriteRule ^foo$ index.php?a=foo [L]` does it work?

Comment: i used exactly 
`Options -Multiviews  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /test/  
RewriteRule ^foo$ index.php?a=foo [L]
`
and then test.testsystem.com/foo there i get an 404
if i use test.testsystem.com/?a=foo i get a output array('a' =>'foo')

Comment: what is the location of your htaccess file?

Comment: i put it now directly in the "test" folder and delete the RewriteBase and now foo works as it should. But do you know how i can setup it like from the initial question? thank you very much amit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `test.domain.com` is pointing to the `/test` folder , you can use something like the following in your `/test/.htaccess` .

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
#1)Rewrite /foo to /index.php?a=foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1  [L]
#2)rewrite /foo/bar to /index.php?a=foo&v=bar
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&v=$2  [L]
#3)rewrite /foo/bar/buzz to /index.php?a=foo&v=bar&z=buzz
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&v=$2&z=$3  [L]
```

The RewriteConds are important in each rules to avoid rewriting your existing files and directories .